# how to create a login authentication with google using angular and firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, google-authentication

The old method for angular login authentication is not working. I have tried to go to @angular/fire npm and work on their example but it gives me a run time error.

- login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  // templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
    <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
    <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  <ng-template #showLogin>
    <p>Please login.</p>
    <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
  </ng-template>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{
 
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }

  }
```

I have installed

- angularcli --version13.1.14 & firebase --version 10.1.1 &  @angular/fire

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11105:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4746:1)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:4750:1)
    at Object.AngularFireAuth_Factory [as factory] (angular-fire-compat-auth.js:126:1)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:11442:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11261:1)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21800:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:1)
    at zone.js:1279:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25437:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1600:1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t got any old references still hanging around somewhere?

Comment: I think so I used npm add @angular/fire

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It seems the documentation is not right.

Comment: Any one who solve this bug please help